# C# Windows Service does not appear as started

Tags: c#, windows, service, onstart

I wrote a little windows service in C#, which should listen on a specific port and do something with a request.

I also wrote the Main like this:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace AutoDeployService
{
    public static class WindowsServiceController
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new AutoDeployService() 
            };

            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                new AutoDeployService().ConsoleRun();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I can start the service with console and without. When i start the program as Console-Application, it works fine!

If I install the service with "InstallUtil.exe" it installs perfect and it appears in the list of services. But when I try to start the service it gives me after about a half minute or more this message:

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

After I researched this error in www I found, that the OnStart-Method can take much time, now my OnStart-Method looks like:

```
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            base.OnStart(args);
            var initializeThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Initialize));
            initializeThread.Start();
        }
```

So I hope anyone can help me.

Greetings

EDIT:
It seems that the service started after I start him with servicemanager, but in servicemanager the error above appears and its defined as not started.

Eventlog:

Name der fehlerhaften Anwendung: AutoDeployService.exe, Version: 1.0.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x5459e290
Name des fehlerhaften Moduls: unknown, Version: 0.0.0.0, Zeitstempel: 0x00000000
Ausnahmecode: 0x00000000
Fehleroffset: 0x0039010b
ID des fehlerhaften Prozesses: 0xa0c
Startzeit der fehlerhaften Anwendung: 0x01cff8d816b830d8
Pfad der fehlerhaften Anwendung:
C:\Users***username***\Desktop\AutoDeploy\AutoDeployService\bin\Debug\AutoDeployService.exe
Pfad des fehlerhaften Moduls: unknown
Berichtskennung: 5d636ccf-64cb-11e4-b5d1-0050568bc9b7

EDIT:

If I start the service, the service doesnt seems to get into the OnStart-Method, because he doesnt creates a folder.

Comment: Check the Windows event log for applications. Also note that it is probably better to check if the debugger is attached `If (Debugger.IsAttached) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

Comment: @Silvermind
Thanks for your fast replay. The message in the Eventlog does not help very much. Please see the edit in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

I found my erorr with attaching the Debugger with this command:

```
Debugger.Launch().
```

Error was in a Thread from my application.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some misunderstanding; although the executable can be started from the command line, the service itself cannot be started from the command line. Furthermore, a tutorial about service creation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, thats what i ment, if i start the executable from console, it works fine. So the error has to be something with the service.
Thank you for your response. I looked at this tutorial but it doesnt help me very much. My service seems to be right.